# listView.SortKey = ColumnHeader.Index - 1

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I am converting VB to VB.NET and I found two error which i have no idea to solve it

```
listView.SortKey = ColumnHeader.Index - 1

listView.Sorted = False
```

I know that `SortKey` is getting the `column index` for sorting and  `listView.Sorted`  is setting turn off or on sorting.

but how is the code in vb.net?

Comment: Use the ListView.ListViewItemSorter property.  There's an example in the MSDN Library article for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.None` to turn off the sort.

To sort on a particular column, you can use the ListViewItemSorter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter.aspx

However, when you have assigned a custom sorting class to the .ListViewItemSorter, you cannot disable the sort. You have to assign a new ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = Nothing AND set SortOrder.None.